How to get the method name with the url using django.urls.get_resolver()
I am getting these urls with django's get_resolver() function for a class:
^api/asset_management/^^get_assets/$
^api/asset_management/^^get_assets\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$
^api/asset_management/^^get_assets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$
^api/asset_management/^^get_assets/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$

I also want the name of the method where each of these url is redirected e.g. Get, Post etc. The class is a simple ModelViewSet and is registered by the DefaultRouter.

It might not be possible to get a 100% correct result here since the method isn't actually stored in the URL pattern but in the view itself and views can be any Python function / method. Answers that support only class based views (builtin generic views from Django or from known packages like Django Rest Framework) should be possible though.

My views are of type viewsets.ModelViewSet which is imported from rest_framework. I am only defining the get_queryset method while the rest is the default functionality. If this information is not stored anywhere then since similar urls are generated for all the ModelViewSet is it possible to parse the url string to determine the endpoint?

If you're using DRF it should be possible to get the information from the view class, my comment focuses more on function based views  (and class based views which either don't inherit from builtin ones or modify the builtin quite a lot)
